# Creating Index on text columns sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table with the following schema

```
Users(
Id         int PK,
FirstName  varchar(255),
SurName    varchar(255) ,
UserName   varchar(255),
City       varchar(255) ,
Country    varchar(255))
```

My application involves searching on `FirstName`, `SurName` and on both `FirstName+SurName` how should I create an Index such that it gives the most optimized timing performance.

Is the given below Index will resolve the purpose

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
USR_FirstNameSurName_IDX 
ON dbo.Users(FirstName,SurName)
```

PS: Due to catalog maintenance overhead I cannot use Full Text Search.

Comment: I would suggest creating a computed column that concatenates the two fields and then creating an index on that.

Comment: why don't you write a search on that table in SSMS and include the actual execution plan. SSMS should then inform you if an index is missing and how it should be

Answer (score 0):

Creating an `Index` on Table will absolutely increase the performance of data retrieval and within the optimum timing. Creating an Index means that, It will re-organize the `Column` data on that table. Your approach is Good and no other way to retrieve the data based on the `FirstName` and `SurName` in optimum except `Indexing`. One more thing Retrieve the needed `Columns` only instead of using `*` in the `Select` list.

I am expecting your Query as follows.

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, SurName
FROM Users
WHERE (FirstName LIKE 'D%' OR SurName LIKE 'D%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed column

```
CREATE table Users(
Id         int primary key identity
,FirstName  varchar(255)
,SurName    varchar(255)
,UserName   varchar(255)
,City       varchar(255)
,Country    varchar(255)
,FullName  AS LTRIM(RTRIM(FirstName)) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(SurName)) 
)

Insert Users(FirstName,  SurName) Values('FirstName' , 'SurName') 
Insert Users(FirstName,  SurName) Values('Siddharth' , 'Bharadwaj')
Insert Users(FirstName,  SurName) Values('Shyam' , 'Vemula')


SELECT FirstName, SurName, FullName FROM Users where FullName like ('%th Bh%')
FirstName                                          SurName                                            FullName
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Siddharth                                          Bharadwaj                                          Siddharth Bharadwaj

(1 row(s) affected)

SELECT FirstName, SurName, FullName FROM Users where FullName like ('%Test%')
FirstName                                          SurName                                            FullName
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

If necessary you can create an index

```
create index akUsersFullName on Users (FullName)
```